# Why does WPF ApplicationCrash on using Listview

Tags: wpf

I ma facing an issue of crashing WPF application.
I have a search screen, it will search on single textbox, have used vertualization, but sometimes it crash while i am on search screen. I have check event viewer and found below information.

i am using very low configuration system for the same application.

```
Application: Lotus.TILL.UI.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: Unrecoverable system error.
Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
   at MS.Internal.Invariant.FailFast(System.String, System.String)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.GridViewItemAutomationPeer..ctor(System.Object, System.Windows.Automation.Peers.ListViewAutomationPeer)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.GridViewAutomationPeer.System.Windows.Automation.Peers.IViewAutomationPeer.CreateItemAutomationPeer(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.ListViewAutomationPeer.CreateItemAutomationPeer(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.ItemsControlAutomationPeer.GetChildrenCore()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.ListViewAutomationPeer.GetChildrenCore()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.EnsureChildren()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateChildrenInternal(Int32)
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.ItemsControlAutomationPeer.UpdateChildren()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireAutomationEvents()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext+InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Window.Show()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
   at Lotus.TILL.Infrastructure.UI.Controls.DialogWindow.OpenDialogWindow(System.Windows.Window, Lotus.TILL.Infrastructure.UI.BaseViewModel, Lotus.TILL.Common.Entities.ReferenceData.DialogAnimationType, System.Object)
   at Lotus.TILL.UI.ShellViewModel.LoadCustomDialog(Double, Double)
   at Lotus.TILL.UI.ShellViewModel.DiscoverDialog(Lotus.TILL.Common.Entities.ToolbarItem, Boolean)
   at Lotus.TILL.UI.ShellViewModel.ShowDialogCommandExecute(System.Object)
   at Lotus.TILL.Infrastructure.UI.Helpers.DelegateCommand.Execute(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(System.Windows.Input.ICommandSource, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at Lotus.TILL.UI.App.Main()
```

Code I am using to search item.

```
public class ShopItemsProvider : IItemsProvider<SaleItem>
    {
        const int _fetchDelay = 200; //ms
        readonly string _searchTxt;
        readonly bool _searchAnyWhere;
        IList<SaleItem> _items;
        readonly SearchType _searchType = SearchType.None;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DemoCustomerProvider"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="count">The count.</param>
        /// <param name="fetchDelay">The fetch delay.</param>
        public ShopItemsProvider(SearchType type, string searchTxt, IList<SaleItem> plofItems, bool searchAnyWhere = false)
        {
            _searchType = type;
            _searchTxt = searchTxt;
            _searchAnyWhere = searchAnyWhere;
            _items = plofItems;
        }

        public int FetchCount()
        {
            return Data.Count();
        }

        public ReadOnlyCollection<SaleItem> PlofItems
        {
            get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<SaleItem>(_items); }
        }

        public IQueryable<SaleItem> Data
        {
            get
            {
                Thread.Sleep(_fetchDelay);

                IEnumerable<SaleItem> data;
                var filteredShopItems = DataRepository.ShopItems.Where(x => x.ItemType == SaleItemType.Grocery || x.ItemType == SaleItemType.News);
                switch (_searchType)
                {
                    case SearchType.ShopItems:
                        data = filteredShopItems;
                        break;
                    case SearchType.PlofItems:
                        data = PlofItems;
                        break;
                    default:
                        return new List<SaleItem>().AsQueryable();
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_searchTxt) || _searchTxt.Length < 1)
                    return data.AsQueryable<SaleItem>();

                if (_searchAnyWhere)
                    return (from rows in data
                            where (rows.Name != null && rows.Name.Contains(_searchTxt, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                               || (rows.ScannedBarcode != null && rows.ScannedBarcode.Contains(_searchTxt, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                            select rows).AsQueryable<SaleItem>();

                return (from rows in data
                        where (rows.Name != null && rows.Name.Trim().StartsWith(_searchTxt, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                           || (rows.ScannedBarcode != null && rows.ScannedBarcode.StartsWith(_searchTxt, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        select rows).AsQueryable<SaleItem>();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fetches a range of items.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="startIndex">The start index.</param>
        /// <param name="count">The number of items to fetch.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IList<SaleItem> FetchRange(int startIndex, int count)
        {
            List<SaleItem> result = null;
            try
            {
                //return Data.OrderBy(c => c.BaseBarcode).Skip(startIndex).Take(count).ToList();
                result = Data.OrderBy(c => c.Name).Skip(startIndex).Take(count).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                UIExceptionHandler.LogException(ex, "Search Fetch Reange Exception");
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Rajnikant

Comment: do please share the code what caused this issue.

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: It crashes the application, and its unhandled exception. it crashes sometimes only, you cant just reproduce strait.

Comment: At the start of the get for Data, there is a Sleep()... Why?

Comment: @Nzc - My system is too slow for WPF, so UI rendering required some delay, and it also does not neccesary to put it there, as i m doing some R & D, so for that i have put it. earlier it was not there. without that delay, it was crashing.

Comment: If actions need to be delayed until the UI is constructed, it is better to syncronize that explicitly. You can use the Loaded event to wait for that. Using Sleep()s to fix such synchronization issues usually means you set yourself up for a nasty race condition.

Comment: but as i said, it is part of only r&d, it was not earlier there.

Comment: Same issue here, only happens on win 8.1 w/ Touch service enabled. Disabling the Touch services "fixes" the problem.

Comment: Did anyone found any solution for this problem? Or steps to diagnose?